# Unable to find tomcat listen port in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

We have created one AWS instance in that i installed the tomacat7 by followng the below command

```
apt-get install tomcat7
```

And in given class path in bashrc file

and started tomcat like below

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

I got the message like

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

But,when i am checking the listen ports i didn't get the tomact port

```
netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

- Can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the tomcat7 service with:

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

The service uses the configuration in `/etc/tomcat7`

That's all.

---

If you want to use your method, then you must first create a configuration.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/conf 
sudo cp /etc/tomcat7/server.xml /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml
```

and start

```
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```